# moving up and down model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, say I have a `Company` that `has_many` `employees`, which `has_many` `posts`. `Company` also `has_many` `contractors.` This is a bit nonsensical, but if I were to start at `posts` and want to go to `contractors`, can I do something like

```
non_employees = post.employee.company.contractors?
```

ignoring the fact that I could just simply do `company.contractors`

Comment: Why *couldn't* you? Note that it would likely be fairly inefficient as shown here due to multiple queries.

Comment: I've said that line myself a few times before getting boned by rails' convention over configuration policy. Well as long as I know it would work.

Comment: another bad thing is, imagine that you don't have the `post.employee` for some reason. When you call `post.employee.company.contractors?` it will explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you remember to use both `has_many` and `belongs_to`, ... depending on which is appropriate in both models, it works !

I'd recommend to make your code as expressive as possible unless performance is an issue (well your exemple might be really too much tho...).